# Random number generation: dealing with "change"

Tags: dice, random, programming

The goal is to generate a random integer between 1-16, inclusive, with a 6 sided die as your only source of randomness. The solution that seems to be staring me in the face is to roll three times and subtract 2 from the sum of the rolls. Three rolls will add to a number between 3-18; subtract 2 to get a number between 1-16, eliminating any unwanted amount over the target.

Does this seem satisfactory, and is there a better way to go about this? The original problem is from a previously used challenge in a scholarship competition for a programming seminar, so this is just for practice. The solution is meant to be a program written in Python; the method for the 6 sided die can be assumed. [Original problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYAKO.png)

Comment: Is the random integer supposed to have a particular distribution? If not, then the problem is trivial, and simply taking the results of one die roll, or even the [xkcd random number generator](https://xkcd.com/221/) would work.

Comment: No, it is not a satisfactory method. The chance of getting a medium result (8 or 9) is much larger than on 1 or 16.

Comment: What you can do is roll the die twice. Then take: outcome = (first-1)*6 + second. You get a number between 1 and 36. Discard and try again when the result is 33 or larger. Convert the result between 1 and 32 to a number from 1 to 16.

Comment: @M.Wind Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "Convert the result between 1 and 32?"

Comment: @AmishNick They mean use any process which process which turns a uniformly distributed number 1-32 into a uniformly distributed number 1-16: e.g. divide by two, rounding up in case of a fractional part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like the integer to be uniformly distributed in the range $1$-$16$, then as explained in the comments this will not work (essentially because the so-called binomial distribution is not uniform).

Since $16$ is a power of $2$, I have a simpler strategy to suggest: view the dice as a degenerate coin, i.e. where odd is heads (a $1$) and even is tails (a $0$). Perform $4$ coin flips: you'll get $4$ ones or zeroes, i.e. binary digits. Writing them down in order gives a binary number in the range $0$-$15$ which is uniformly distributed. Add 1 to get your desired result.

Comment: I like this; I had some vague instinct that using a different base would be a good workaround but wasn't sure how to implement it.